# Changing the text in a textbox with type date ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, textbox

I am trying to set a text box (which is type = "Date") to a string value which I have taken in from a database.

I have tried the following:

```
txtDOB.Text = tempRow["DOB"].ToString();
txtDOB.Attributes = tempRow["DOB"].ToString();
```

But unfortunately I am having no luck with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try formatting it like String.Format(tempRow[“DOB”],”yyyy-mm-did”);

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, it just remains on the starting value of "dd/mm/yyyy". It seems that it doesn't behave like a normal textbox when i change the type = "Date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have a valid value in tempRow["DOB"].

```
var dob = Convert.ToDateTime(tempRow["DOB"]);
```

After that, you can simply:

```
txtDOB.Text = dob.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
txtDOB.Attributes = dob.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is due to the textbox not understanding the string format of the data you are providing it.

Try changing your code to this:

```
txtDOB.Text = tempRow["DOB"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
txtDOB.Attributes = tempRow["DOB"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Validate when debugging (by using the Immediate window of Visual Studio) to see if "tempRow["DOB"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" spits out a valid date string.

Comment: Although this would work with the likes of DateTime.Now(), it wouldn't work with the tempRow. It was overloading the .ToString(). Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Ah I was assuming your row was of type DateTime - we use DevExpress MySql connectors and in our apps the rows are cast to primitive types.